# Disable proof of work in Whisper

Tags: private-blockchain, proof-of-work, whisper

I have a private network and am looking to disable Whisper's required Proof of Work when sending a message. [This issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14853) talks about how the source prevents this, but I'm wondering if there's another way aside from forking the code and allowing it. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the Whisper experts can probably comment further, but from a cursory look at the code: no, almost certainly not.

It looks like the only way to do it in Whisperv5 is by forking and editing the code to remove the target checks. Though you also could set it to a very small value like 0.0000001. In v6 you can set it to 0.

Comment: thank you, you're right in v5 you can't. I'm going to post an answer from Gitter with some clarifications.

Comment: Combined the gitter comments with your answer, thanks Richard.